# Check if Fiscal Code already exists during Checkout [WOOCOMMERCE]

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout, woocommerce-checkout-fields

Good morning everybody,

I'm trying to introduce a fiscal code verification during my checkout.
The verification is similar to what Wordpress does with email.

I created a similar "email_exists()" function to check if the fiscal code in the order already exists and then I put a function to give a warning if this fiscal code exists.

Here's the code:

```
function cf_exists( $order_cf ) {
   $order_cf =  $order->billing_address_2;
   $user = get_user_by( 'fiscalcode', $billing_address_2 );
   if ( $user ) {
       $user_id = $user->ID;
   } else {
       $user_id = false;

function cf_check(){
if ( cf_exists( $order_cf ) ) {
       return new WP_Error( 'registration-error-fc-exists', __( 'An account is already registered with your fiscal code. Please login.', 'woocommerce' ) ); 
}
```

As usual, Wordpress breaks itself and I don't understand what I'm missing.
Hope to get some help, thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Just a little note: I used the Billing Address 2 as Fiscal Code Field intentionally, it's not a mistypo

Comment: `$order` is not defined, so that's where the problem seems to be. You also do not indicate in your question from where you call the function? Please make sure your question contains  [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Good morning 7uc1f3r, thanks for the link!
I'm still new to php and woocommerce programming so sometimes I made this kind of mistake, I'll provide more correct informations from now!

Comment: On the checkout page, the $order object doesn't exist yet. As I mentioned, **edit your question** and **add the necessary details** needed so that someone can answer your question. 
Where did you add this code? are you calling it through a hook? from a template file?

Answer (score 1):

Just missing a few closing brackets and you messed a bit with function arguments. Also it's get_billing_address_2() and you need to return something:

```
function cf_exists( $order ) {
   $order_cf =  $order->get_billing_address_2();
   $user = get_user_by( 'fiscalcode', $billing_address_2 );
   if ( $user ) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}

function cf_check( $order ){
   if ( ! cf_exists( $order ) ) {
       wc_add_notice( __( 'An account is already registered with your fiscal code. Please login.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Businessbloomer for the correction and the information!
I tried to implement it but it doesn't show any error message.

I tried to replace the "return new WP_Error" with "return $errors->add( 'validation', 'Error' );" but it doesn't show anything too.

Do you have some suggestions to make this message appear? Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Ciao Luca :) I'd need more context i.e. when are you calling the function and where? Basically the rest of the code so that I know if/when it triggers

Comment: I'll try my best to give you more context!
I'm calling the function during the checkout phase, when you make the order.
The error message I want to show is similar to the ones when you don't input a required field.

The flow is like this:
User inserts his data in the checkout fields and then it clicks the order button.
The function will check if the fiscal code already exists: if yes, it will displays the error message above the checkout form, where all the other errors appear (just to give the context)

Comment: Ok, try this new version